# Multiple instances of Verticles: Is the Context shared or always separate?

Tags: vert.x

I plan to have a verticle that uses the Context object to store intermediate results. Basically it does the following:

1. Wait for incoming requests R.
2. If a request R comes in, send sub-requests to some other verticles V1-VN
3. Wait for the results of V1..VN
4. If a reply from V1..VN comes in, process and store the result from this reply in the Context object using a unique key and modifiable list of these results.
5. If all replies are in, reply to the request R with all the sub-replies from V1..VN

Now if I run this (standard) verticle in multiple instances (DeploymentOptions.setInstances(4), do the verticle share a Context or does each have its own Context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, each Verticle has its own context.

https://github.com/eclipse/vert.x/blob/6a01366c8b86f4d4431d9e97d775c45628dcd0ce/src/test/java/io/vertx/test/core/ContextTest.java#L91

To share data between verticles, used `vertx.sharedData()`.